# "Napoleon suppressed independent banks" vs. "Monte dei Paschi di Siena"

Tags: napoleonic-wars, banking

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_of_Saint_George) about Bank of Saint George states that:

> After Napoleon invaded Italy, he suppressed independent banks, and this led to the Bank's closure in 1805.

However [Monte dei Paschi di Siena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_dei_Paschi_di_Siena) (MPS) has been operating continuously since 1472.

The Italian and the English Wikipedia entries on either bank say nothing about it; nor does the entry on the [Grand Duchy of Tuscany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duchy_of_Tuscany#Tuscany_during_the_French_Revolutionary_and_Napoleonic_Wars).

So, since Tuscany was eventually all under Napoleon's control, did he actually try but fail to close all banks, or is that statement "just wrong", or was MPS still active but under state control, or what?

Comment: A likely answer in this book (which seems to be at least in part in English) which is available only in snippets: Monte dei paschi di Siena: Banca fondata nel 1472 : Historical Notes  http://books.google.com/books?id=5DIiAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Monte+dei+Paschi+di+Siena%22+napoleon&dq=%22Monte+dei+Paschi+di+Siena%22+napoleon&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2A_CUtHkNYyDkQfS7IDYCg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA

Comment: Monte dei Paschi di Siena was part of the Kingdom of Etruria from 1801 until 1807, the time period in which the Bank of Saint George (based in Genoa) was disbanded. Perhaps by then Napoleon was less interested in the process.